# Detect which scrollbar was moved with the wheel event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Let's say we have a simple HTML page with div container that has vertical scrollbar. The whole page also contains vertical scrollbar:

[image: scrollbars]

I would like to disable the main body scrollbar feature (but it should be visible as it is) and allow user to scroll only the container's content.

I know that the only option to disable scrolling is catching the `wheel` event and calling `preventDefault` on it. However it disables all scrollbars.

Is it possible to obtain, which scroll will be affected with the event (container's or global one) and conditionally call the `preventDefault` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below is written in jQuery, but it can be done in plain Javascript equivalent code as well:

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', context, function(ev) {
    //Do some stuff
    ev.stopPropagation(); //Prevents ancestors of context of handling the event
});
```